# pass a Tag to a project Sonarqube via Yaml Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

I want to tag my sonarqube projects automatically, via azure Devops.

I tried, but without success, the pipeline runs but doesn't tag the project.

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: Add Tag Sonarqube
  inputs:
    script: 'curl -X POST urlsonarqube/api/project_tags/set?project=NameProject&tags=NameTags'
```

Is any token missing?

> Sonarqube Community Edition Version 8.2

Answer (score 0):

This method requires POST method according to documentation
https://sonarqube.inria.fr/sonarqube/web_api/api/project_tags

Yout command uses GET method.
Try to use 'curl -X POST urlsonarqube/api/project_tags/set?project=NameProject&tags=NameTags'

Comment: I had used it like this, in some tests, I just forgot to mention it in the question, it doesn't give an error, it gives the green light that everything went well, but it doesn't create the tag in sonarqube.

Comment: Are you sure you authenticate properly and have qdministrator rights for that project? https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/web-api/

Comment: Yes, I'm authenticated and I made a change, I tried using the Admin token in the curl -u token call, but still to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

After much researching, we found the right solution.

```
 - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script: 'curl -u tokenSonarqube: -X POST ''https://urlsonarqube/api/project_tags/set?project=ProjectName&tags=Tag1,Tag2,Tag3'''
```

**There is no limitation on the number of tags**